# Azure: whats the difference between "Reserved IP Address" and "Public IP Address"

Tags: networking, azure

Whats the difference between these two resource types, and which should I create?

My scenario is I need to setup an unknown number of jmeter load test servers (which will be linux VMs which I manually install jmeter server), but the website I need to load test requires the incoming IP to be whitelisted, which takes 3-4 weeks as it has to go through a production release cycle.  So I need to create say 8 ips now, whitelist them, then when the web.config of teh episerver website is updated, I can finally do the load testing.

I dont know how many IPs, as I dont know how many Jmeter servers Ill need to simulate 10,000 users hitting the website at 2 pages a minute.  I am hoping 8 will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved IP addresses is an old name for Classic Azure Resource, you should consider two kind of [SKU](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses) (Basic and Standard) when creating a Public IP. There are two options for your needs, please have a look at [NAT Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway-resource), basically you will have only one IP for your outbound traffic, then you whitelisted this IP. The second option is to reserve a [Public IP address prefix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-address-prefix), basically it reserves a network (example /28) to be used, it is always SKU standard.

**SKU Standard**

> Azure allows you to reserve a public IPv4 address in your Azure Subscription. You can own these IP addresses for as long as you want in your subscription and also associate them with your Cloud Service Deployments in the region of the Reserved IP addresses. The IP address is NOT released when you stop (or delete) the resource.

**SKU Basic**

> The IP address is released when you stop (or delete) the resource when static option is not selected.

---

In case you don't want to lose your IP even when stopping your VM, just remember to select this option.

The IP address is released when the allocation method is changed from static to dynamic. To ensure the IP address for the associated resource remains the same, set the allocation method explicitly to static. A static IP address is assigned immediately.

[image]

Comment: I created some "public ip addresses". i havent assigned them to a vm yet. I was planning to assing them to a vm, later stop the vm to save cost, later recreated the VM and assign it the same ip as the old one. Are you saying that paying for a "pubic ip address" then assigning it to a vm, I will lose the ip when the VM is switched off? This kind of defeats the point no?  I still dont know if I should be using a "reseved ip address", basic "public IP address" or standard "public IP address". They seem very similar, and the differences are not very well explained (at least for layman?)

Comment: Ok, in case you don't want to lose your IP, just remember to select STATIC IP (see imagem above). Even when you stop a VM you won't lose your IP, once you start a VM you can attach this public IP to VM. This IP will be always available for you. The IP address is released when the allocation method is changed from static to dynamic. To ensure the IP address for the associated resource remains the same, set the allocation method explicitly to static. A static IP address is assigned immediately.